# H2S Sensor with 1 PPB Lower Detection Limit

Tags: sensor, development, gas-sensor, gas, research

We're trying to create an IoT device that can detect/mesaure H2S in ambient air with a
**lower detection limit of 1 ppb or 0.001 ppm**

However, checking Digikey and other similar suppliers, I haven't found any sensors that fit this requirement. Below are examples of what I've found:

DGS-CO 968-034:
https://www.spec-sensors.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/DGS-CO-968-034.pdf

ZE03 Electrochemical Gas Sensor Module:
https://www.winsen-sensor.com/d/files/PDF/Gas%20Sensor%20Module/Industrial%20Application%20Gas%20Sensor%20Module/ZE03%20Electrochemical%20Module%20V2.4.pdf

What we've found are already existing devices, which are classified as H2S Analyzers:

Model T101 UV Fluorescence H2S Analyzers: http://www.teledyne-ml.com/products_/instruments/gaseous/sulfur/Documents/T101.pdf

Serinus 55 H2S Analyzers: https://www.ecotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/ECOTECH-Serinus-55-Brochure.pdf

We've already considered integrating with existing devices, but we want to see if we can develop our own device.

Does anyone know of a commercially-available sensor that can fit this requirement?
Or perhaps, a company that makes these sensors on request?

Comment: Looks like a shopping question. If you were to ask how to *design* an H2S sensor, or how to *use* one, that would be another matter.

Comment: Google turns up lots of companies making gas sensors in the PPB range.  Try emailing what you want and see if they can sell you a solution.